# python 3 send email with different subject and body

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code below to send myself some emails. I need to have the variables bodyemail and subjectEmail be changed randomly. What is the best way to do this? I have some text in an Excel file, but I am not sure if that makes sense to pull the data from there change the two variables, or even how to do that.

```
 import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


fromaddr = "Y@X.com"
toaddr = "X@X.com"
subjectEmail = "Subject"
bodyemail = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = subjectEmail

body = bodyemail
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "Password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that make sense ? It seems the best option. Iterate over each line in that file and use the info to send your emails. Another option would be to store the data in a database but that would just complicate your code. Just stick with the file option

Comment: Sounds good. I am having a hard time figuring out how to store the data as a variable and loop though it. e.g my csv looks like this: subject,body